# Lookup by slug and id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have the following in my products controller show action:

```
@product = Spree::Product.active.where(slug: params[:id]).first!
```

This only works when slug is passed, I want to be able to pass in id or slug and for it to work:

kinda like:

```
Spree::Product.active.where(slug: params[:id]).first! || Spree::Product.active.where(id: params[:id]).first!
```

Right now when I type `products/foo-bar` it works, not when I type `products/1`

Is there a way to do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.first!
```

Raises error when record not found.
Try

```
Spree::Product.active.find_by(slug: params[:id]) || Spree::Product.active.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

It'll try second query if first does not return value

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to search for both in a `where` like so:

```
Spree::Product.active.where("slug = :parameter OR id = :parameter", parameter: params[:id]).first!
```

This will find the `Spree::Product` where either the `slug` or `id` is equal to the `params[:id]`.

Comment: I get ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous

Comment: What is the table name? You can change `id` to `table_name.id` if it is complaining.

Comment: What didn't work? It said that `"spree_products.id"` was ambiguous? Did you also add `"spree_products.slug"`? `Spree::Product.active.where("spree_products.slug = :parameter OR spree_products.id = :parameter", parameter: params[:id]).first!`

Comment: I tried on the console: `[23] pry(main)> Spree::Product.where("spree_products.slug = :parameter OR spree_products.id = :parameter", parameter: 1060501288)`

Comment: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...ts"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (spree_products.slug = 10605012...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "spree_products".* FROM "spree_products"  WHERE "spree_products"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (spree_products.slug = 1060501288 OR spree_products.id = 1060501288)